# ionic images are not show on load until touch image for fullmodal - ionic3

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

```
<ion-content>
<ion-slides class="image-slider" loop="false" slidesPerView="1">
<ion-slide *ngFor="let item of imageList">
<ion-thumbnail>
<ion-img [src]="item" class="thumb-img" (click)="presentModal(item)"></ion-img>
</ion-thumbnail>
</ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

I got a very strange problem.

How to fix it? after touch image for fullmodal image to show

Comment: Which is the problem?

Comment: you are using `ion-img` which should be used only with virtual scroll. Are you using virtual scroll?

Comment: I cannot use img. it's blank

Answer (score 3):

`ion-img` is used to cache images when `virtualScroll` is being used. It is not an independent component. Since there is no virtualScroll in the given code, you should be using html `img` tag.

Use `img`.

```
<img [src]="item" class="thumb-img" (click)="presentModal(item)"/>
```

Refer: [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/img/Img/)

Comment: broken images it's not load

Comment: check if the image links are valid

Comment: it's valid. because after touch broken images it show fullmodal

Comment: "it show fullmodal" maybe because you are calling on click.. doesnt mean img src is returning valid image.. check the link

Comment: <img src="{{imageScreen(imageList)}}" class="thumb-img" (click)="presentModal(item)"/>

Comment: this.imageList = [];
        this.storage.get('imageScreen').then((val) => {
          this.imageList = val;
        });

Comment: this page get image from storage