# *ngIf not working with <ion-img> in ionic

Tags: ionic3, angular5

In following *ngIf not working with `<ion-img>`

```
<ion-img width="24" height="13" src="assets/imgs/filter.png" *ngIf="sortTypeIndustryWise=='AZ'"></ion-img>
<ion-img width="24" height="13" src="assets/imgs/filter-upside.png" *ngIf="sortTypeIndustryWise=='ZA'"></ion-img>
```

If I simply use `<img>` tag then this works fine

```
 <img width="24" height="13" src="assets/imgs/filter.png" *ngIf="sortTypeIndustryWise=='AZ'"/>
 <ion-img width="24" height="13" src="assets/imgs/filter-upside.png" *ngIf="sortTypeIndustryWise=='ZA'"/>
```

Why *ngIf not working with `<ion-img>`

Comment: are you using virtualscroll?

Comment: @SurajRao No I am not using virtualscroll

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ionic images are not show on load until touch image for fullmodal - ionic3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48259425/ionic-images-are-not-show-on-load-until-touch-image-for-fullmodal-ionic3)

Comment: ion-img is used only with virtualscroll. Your code is otherwise fine. Check my answer in duplicate

Comment: @SurajRao thanks a lot to clear concept wise.I am using <img> tag now